# Get value of first object property

Tags: javascript, object

I have a simple object that always has one `key:value` like `var obj = {'mykey':'myvalue'}`

What is the fastest way and elegant way to get the value without really doing this?

```
for (key in obj) {
  console.log(obj[key]);
  var value = obj[key];
}
```

Like can I access the value via index 0 or something?

Comment: Please note that the problem has **nothing** to do with JSON at all. It seems you are confusing JavaScript object literals (constructs of the JavaScript language syntax) with JSON (a language-independent data-exchange format, like XML or CSV). I will edit your question accordingly. See also: [There is no such thing as a "JSON object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Comment: *related*: [JavaScript: Get first and only property name of object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6765864/javascript-get-first-and-only-property-name-of-object)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
var value = obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]];
```

`Object.keys` is included in javascript 1.8.5. Please check the compatibility here http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#Object.keys

**Edit:**

This is also defined in javascript 1.8.5 only.

```
var value = obj[Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj)[0]];
```

**Reference:**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FGuide%2FWorking_with_Objects#Enumerating_all_properties_of_an_object

Answer (score 1):

```
function firstProp(obj) {
    for(var key in obj)
        return obj[key]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.values()`

```js
const obj = {
  myKeyA: 'my value A',
  myKeyB: 'my value B',
}

const [valueOfFirstObjectProperty] = Object.values(obj)

console.log('Value:', valueOfFirstObjectProperty) // my value A
```