# Return array iteration

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got the following component where I pull in some JSON and I'm trying to get some nested information with `{ this.state.data.items[0]}`, however I get the error:`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`, although `{this.state.data}` and `{this.state.data.items}` works as well

Here's the full code:

```
var Box = React.createClass({
      getInitialState: function () {
    return {data: []};
  },
  loadStuffFromServer: function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: this.props.url,
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({data: data});
        console.log(data);
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.loadStuffFromServer();
    setInterval(this.loadStuffFromServer, this.props.pollInterval);
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        { this.state.data.items[0]}
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: this.state.data.items is an object, not an array !

Comment: This post explains you how to get the first value of an object http://stackoverflow.com/a/19138293/4774263

Comment: try putting `this.loadStuffFromServer()` in `componentWillMount()`. You only have `data` in your initial state, not `data.items`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getInitialState` should looks like this

```
getInitialState: function () {
    return { 
       data: {
          items: []
       } 
    };
},
```

because `render` calls before `componentDidMount`., you are trying get property `items` from `state.data` but this property does not exists

```
this.state.data       // => returns empty Array
```

then you are trying get property `items`

```
this.state.data.items // => returns undefined
```

because `data` does not have property `items`.,

then you are trying get first element from `items` `Array` but previous statement returned `undefined`, and that's why you get `Error`, because you can not get properties from `undefined` value

Answer (score 0):

render function can not get your data.item from initial state.you should need to change :

```
this.state.data.map(function(d){ return d.items[0] });
```