# Check if object with same properties is in array - coffeescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, coffeescript, equality

So I'm building a filtering system. I have an array of key-value-pair(kvp) objects and I want to check if a kvp has already been added. If the kvp has I want to remove it, and if it hasn't I want to add it to the array. However I'm having trouble checking deep equality. I can't use an object instead of an array because the keys can be the same (e.g. `{state: TX}` and `{state: NE}`). This code doesn't check deep equality so it always pushes a new kvp.

```
if kvp in filters
    pos = filters.indexOf(kvp)
    filters.splice(pos, 1)
else
    filters.push(kvp)
```

I tried this as well, but it also didn't check for deep equality (as well as filters exponentially growing).

```
if filters.length == 0
    filters.push(kvp)
else
    for filter in filters
        if kvp == filter
            pos = filters.indexOf(filter)
            filters.splice(pos, 1)
        else
            filters.push(kvp)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: How complex is the structure of the objects?

Comment: The objects are very simple, just one property with one value.

Comment: Just compare that property then. See the duplicate question.

Comment: @FelixKling The property itself is could be anything, so is there a simpler way than calling getOwnPropertyNames on the filter, checking if that property is not undefined on the kvp, and then comparing the values?

Comment: How about [JavaScript: Get first and only property name of object](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6765864/218196) ?