# Accessing the value of a property with a known name that is nested in a JSON object with vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

Thank you for taking the time to read my question! I am new to JavaScript and have been unable to find a solution to the following question:

How can I access the value of a property that is nested in a JSON object under a property whose name dynamically changes?

The JSON object:

```
{
  "batchcomplete": "",
  "query": {
    "normalized": [
      {
        "from": "Theodore_Rubin",
        "to": "Theodore Rubin"
      }
    ],
    "pages": {
      "11820415": {
        "pageid": 11820415,
        "ns": 0,
        "title": "Theodore Rubin",
        "contentmodel": "wikitext",
        "pagelanguage": "en",
        "pagelanguagehtmlcode": "en",
        "pagelanguagedir": "ltr",
        "touched": "2016-02-12T17:34:52Z",
        "lastrevid": 138813300,
        "length": 34,
        "redirect": "",
        "new": "",
        "fullurl": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theodore_Rubin",
        "editurl": "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Theodore_Rubin&action=edit",
        "canonicalurl": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theodore_Rubin"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to assign the value of the property `fullurl` to a variable. I understand that I can use a combination of bracket and dot notation to access the `fullurl` such as `query.pages["2123909"].fullurl`. The problem is that the property name `["2123909"]` changes with each JSON request.

How can I access the value of `fullurl` property without knowing the name of the property that it is nested in?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: If there is always only one property, see [JavaScript: Get first and only property name of object](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6765864/218196)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is only one key, you could get the first element with [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object.keys) of `data.query.pages`.

```js
var data = {
        "batchcomplete": "",
        "query": {
            "normalized": [
              {
                  "from": "Theodore_Rubin",
                  "to": "Theodore Rubin"
              }
            ],
            "pages": {
                "11820415": {
                    "pageid": 11820415,
                    "ns": 0,
                    "title": "Theodore Rubin",
                    "contentmodel": "wikitext",
                    "pagelanguage": "en",
                    "pagelanguagehtmlcode": "en",
                    "pagelanguagedir": "ltr",
                    "touched": "2016-02-12T17:34:52Z",
                    "lastrevid": 138813300,
                    "length": 34,
                    "redirect": "",
                    "new": "",
                    "fullurl": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theodore_Rubin",
                    "editurl": "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Theodore_Rubin&action=edit",
                    "canonicalurl": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theodore_Rubin"
                }
            }
        }
    };

console.log(data.query.pages[Object.keys(data.query.pages)[0]].fullurl);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the object has always only one property name, [get the property name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6765864/218196) and access the property via bracket notation:

```
var key = // see https://stackoverflow.com/q/6765864/218196
query.pages[key].fullurl
```

If there are more more than one property, iterate over the object, e.g. via `for...in`. See [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json) for that.