# How to reference JSON set as key in Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have a Nodejs lambda function that needs to parse JSON sent to it from an external application. The JSON appears to be malformed and comes in as an object key like so:

```
 console.log(req.body)
```

results in:

`{ '{"id":"258830096441","time":10}': '' }`

What I need is the id and id number, but I am stumped as to how I could parse this.

Comment: Is typeof `req.body` a string or an object?

Comment: [Get its key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6765864/4642212), then parse it as JSON.

Comment: Could you copy the code where you are reading the request?

Comment: req.body is an object. 

the code just looks like this:

exports.main = async function(req, res) {
console.log(req.body)}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `req.body` is an object, you can get the first `key` of the array returned by [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and then [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) that key to finally get the `id`. Like shown on next example:

```js
const obj = { '{"id":"258830096441","time":10}': '' };

let id = JSON.parse(Object.keys(obj)[0]).id;

console.log(id, typeof id); // As string.
console.log(+id, typeof +id); // As number, in case you need the id as number.
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse out the key by doing `Object.keys(req.body)[0]`, which will give you a string, and then you can convert this string to an object by calling `JSON.parse` on it. The end result would look something like:

```
let myReqBody = JSON.parse(Object.keys(req.body)[0])
```

Then you can access the attributes of `myReqBody` like you normally would:

```
myReqBody.id
```