# How to sort array of objects with unique keys by nested object value

Tags: javascript, sorting

Really struggling to find a solution here. I have the following data:

```
var arr = [
   { Main: {type: "object", ...} }
   { Poller: {type: "object", ...} }
   { connection: {type: "array", ...} }
   { Profile1: {type: "array", ...} }
   { Sender: {type: "object", ...} }
   { Profile2: {type: "array", ...} }
];
```

My goal is to generate an array that lists the objects of `type: array` first. I tried various implementations of the sort() method but don't know how to account for each nested object having its' own key. Any help is appreciated

Comment: please add your try.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6765864/476?

Comment: `arr.sort((a,b)=>(Object.values(b)[0].type==="array")-(Object.values(a)[0].type==="array"))`

Comment: @gorak I didn't know about Object.values, this is perfect, thank you. IDK how to mark your answer as correct

Comment: @AlecSelinger I wrote you an answer while Gorak was commenting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this

```js
var arr = [
   { Main:       {type: "object",}},
   { Poller:     {type: "object",}},
   { connection: {type: "array" ,}},
   { Profile1:   {type: "array" ,}},
   { Func1:      {type: "function",}},
   { func2:      {type: "function",}},
   { Sender:     {type: "object",}},
   { Profile2:   {type: "array" ,}}
];

arr.sort((a, b) => {
  if (Object.values(a)[0].type < Object.values(b)[0].type) return -1
  if (Object.values(a)[0].type === Object.values(b)[0].type) return 0
  if (Object.values(a)[0].type > Object.values(b)[0].type) return 1
})
console.log(arr)
```